# Django Many2Many Annotation

Tags: python, django

I have two Django tables: `A` and `B`. There's a many2many relationship between them, written in table `A`.

The problem I have is that when I serve this as an API and I present the objects as `A.objects.all().values()`, the values of `B` don't showup.

I want to annotate Django table `A` with the `ids` of the many2many relationship, so that I can pull them when I do `A.objects.all().values()`, to get `A.B_ids=['134','141','1414']`.

For example, this will do, but I have a gut feeling anytime I do iterations in Django, it could be done faster:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def pull_tasks():
    a_values = list(A.objects.all().values())

    for a in a_values:
        a['b_values'] = (A.objects.get(id=a['id']).b.all().values())
    return Response(a_values, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: I find it quite strange that `.values()` is used. This is typically only done to perform a certain selection over the comments. But nevertheless, I think you solve the problem at the wrong layer: this is typically where one uses a serializer.

Comment: See for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439544/67579. Can you share the current approach for the API?

Comment: Check the new edit on the question.

Comment: The edit doesn't help. This is not a job for values, it is a job for a serializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a quick fix, by using `.values_list('id', flat=True)` and by working on the `B` model in the query for the many-to-many relation. For example:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def pull_tasks():
    a_values = list(A.objects.all().values())

    for a in a_values:
        a['b_values'] = list(B.objects.filter(a_id=a['id']).values_list('id', flat=True))
    return Response(a_values, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

So now we construct a simple list of of ids for the related `B` elements, but this is not very efficient, since we perform a fetch for *every* `A` object, which can easily get very expensive.

What you here basically do is writing a *serializer*. But Django has already support for that, by writing a serializer: by using the Django REST framework. For example:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, PrimaryKeyRelatedField

class ASerializer(ModelSerializer):
    skills_ids = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=False,
        queryset=B.objects.all(),
        source='b'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = A
```

You can then for example use as view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def pull_tasks():
    ser = ASerializer(A.objects.prefetch_related('B'), many=True)
    return Response(ser.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

By using a `prefetch_related(..)`, we will fetch all related `B`s in just another query, instead of querying once per `A` object.

Comment: That serializer is what I was looking for. Thanks for the detailed example!